# How to show that $2$, $1+\sqrt{-3}$, and $1-\sqrt{-3}$ are primes in $Z[\sqrt{-3}]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Seems I should use something related to norm map.

Comment: They are irreducible, but not primes. $$2\cdot 2 = 4 = (1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})$$

Comment: Actually the original question is : Show that $4=2\cdot 2=(1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})$ implies that $Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ does not have unique factorization into primes. Hint: Unise the norm map to show that $2, 1+\sqrt{-3}$, and $1-\sqrt{-3}$ are primes in {Z[\sqrt{-3}]}.

Comment: To add on Daniel Fischer's comment, an non zero element $p$ of an integral domain is (usually) called *prime* if it's not invertible and, from $p\mid ab$ it follows that $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ (for any $a$ and $b$ in the domain). It is *irreducible* if it's not invertible and from $p=ab$ it follows that either $a$ or $b$ is invertible. From the statement you add in comment, it seems that your textbook uses “prime” for “irreducible”.

Comment: I just have question how to show these three elements are primes(or say irreducible).

Comment: Okay, now the terminological thing is clarified, in medias res. The idea of using the norm is good. 1. What is the norm of each of these? 2. What norm would a hypothetical (non-unit, non-associated) divisor have? 3. Why is that impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint (to show that they are irreducible):

> if $a+b\sqrt{-3}=(x+y\sqrt{-3})(u+v\sqrt{-3})$ then
>   $$a^2+3b^2=(x^2+3y^2)(u^2+3v^2)$$